# "invalid framebuffer operation" on glClear - using sRGB in OpenGL ES3

Tags: ios, xcode, opengl-es

Using openGL-ES3, running on an iPhone5s (hardware, not in the simulator) in Xcode 7.3 I receive an "invalid framebuffer operation" when doing a glClear.

The texture in question is a "final" texture for my GBuffer, much like in this tutorial http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial37/tutorial37.html.
Key difference being that I'm requesting an sRGB texture and that I use GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT3 (instead of 4), due to ES3 limitations.

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_SRGB8, WindowWidth, WindowHeight, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
// glTexParameteri ...
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT3, GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_finalTexture, 0);
GLenum Status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER); // No errors here
```

Now when I try to clear it, I get an "invalid framebuffer operation"

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, m_fbo);
// Element at index**[i]** needs to match GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT**i** on GL-ES3!
GLenum drawbuf[4] = { GL_NONE, GL_NONE, GL_NONE, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT3 };
glDrawBuffers(sizeof(drawbuf)/sizeof(drawbuf[0]), drawbuf); 

GLCheckError();  // no errors
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); 
GLCheckError();  // => glGetError 506 GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION
```

Now if instead I initialise the texture like this (so without sRGB), OpenGL doesn't give an error on the clear:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB8, WindowWidth, WindowHeight, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
```

Now as I understood it, sRGB *is* supported on OpenGL ES3... so why does glClear fail? 
Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GL_SRGB8` is not a color-renderable format in ES 3.0. In the spec document:

- In the "Required Texture Format" section starting on page 128, `SRGB8` is listed under "Texture-only color formats".
- In table 3.13, starting on page 130, `SRGB8` does not have a checkmark in the "Color-renderable" column.

This also matches the [EXT_srgb](https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/EXT/EXT_sRGB.txt) extension specification, under "Issues":

> Do we require SRGB8_EXT be supported for RenderbufferStorage?
>
> No.  Some hardware would need to pad this out to RGBA and instead of adding that unknown for application  developers we will simply not support that format in this extension.

`glCheckFramebufferStatus()` should return `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT` in this case. If it's not doing that, that looks like a bug in the OpenGL implementation.

The closest alternative that is color-renderable is `GL_SRGB8_ALPHA8`.

Comment: This solves the problem - indeed I didn't notice that GL_SRGB is not color-renderable (weblink: https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man3/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml) - but it definitely returns GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE when creating the framebuffer. Changing it to GL_SRGB8_ALPHA8 works, glClear doesn't report any errors anymore. Thanks also for the extract from the extension, that explains why it's not supported and it makes sense now.

Answer (score 0):

try this
 #define GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT                              0x00004000

glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);